# CSS Transitions Stopped Working - SAFARI

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transitions, css-animations

CSS Transitions work in safari but after navigating to another page and then when you go back to the page with the animation, it doesn't work and you need to clear cache for it to work again.

What's wrong?

Here is the code and a fiddle link, it works in JSFiddle but when applied to the site we have the problem.

HTML

```
<a class="prevtest" href="javascript:void(0);">Test</a>
```

CSS

```
.prevtest {display: block; background: url('http://www.scadmoa.org/sites/all/themes/scadmoa/images/thin-blue-right-arrow.png') no-repeat right center; width: 100%; }

.prevtest {
  background-position: 34px center;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: background-position 0.4s linear;
  transition: background-position 0.4s linear;
}

.prevtest:hover {
  background-position: 40px center;
  -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 0.4s linear;
  -moz-animation: animatedBackground 0.4s linear;
  -o-animation: animatedBackground 0.4s linear;
  animation: animatedBackground 0.4s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% { background-position: 34px center; }
100% { background-position: 40px center; }
}
@-moz-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% { background-position: 34px center; }
100% { background-position: 40px center; }
}
@-o-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% { background-position: 34px center; }
100% { background-position: 40px center; }
}
@-ms-keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% { background-position: 34px center; }
100% { background-position: 40px center; }
}
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  0% { background-position: 34px center; }
100% { background-position: 40px center; }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyxj3rca/2/

Comment: you're going to have to post code or better yet recreate this in a fiddle for help

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyxj3rca/2/

Comment: you want loop animation, or just one-time background repositioning?

Comment: Just one-time background repositioning